# Is it possible to assign our own font name ( .ttf file created from some applications like font forge) to font name property of TEdit in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, fonts

I want convert my own fonts to .ttf files so that all the font processing(display of characters from files) can be handled by OS instead of writing code to display the characters(whose pixels data present in some files). I have found some applications to .ttf file creation(like font forge).
Is it possible to assign this newly created font to font name property of Edit in Delphi 2010?

Comment: Sure, once you've installed your font it will become just another font available for applications, including Delphi.

Comment: Or you can load them on-demand into memory.

Comment: Couldn't you figure this out yourself in about 2 seconds? After installing your font in the OS, start the IDE, drop a label on a form, and try to assign your font name?

Answer (score 6):

You must install a font into the OS before it can then be used in applications.

You can certainly set a UI control's font name to your custom font at design-time (provided the font is installed in your development machine's OS).  If you want to deploy the font with your app, then you need to either:

1. have your app installer install the font before the app is run.
2. have your app use [`AddFontResource/Ex()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326.aspx) or [`AddFontMemResourceEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183325.aspx) to install the font dynamically in code, such as during app startup, before then loading its UI.

Comment: May also be worth noting you need to unload the font on shutdown, or else it will get stuck in memory until the Windows user is logged out. Even if the application is closed, the font is still stuck open.

Comment: @JerryDodge The docs says `When the process goes away, the system will unload the fonts even if the process did not call RemoveFontMemResource.`

Comment: @RepeatUntil We seem to be talking about two different things. I was referring to `AddFontResource...` but you're talking about `AddFontMemResource...`. Actually I had no success with `AddFontMemResourceEx` at that time, so I reverted to just `AddFontResourceEx`.